# Converting INT to Time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in sql that is an INT and I have to convert it to time.

I've tried

```
         CONVERT (VARCHAR, columnA / 600000)
   + ':'
   + RIGHT ('00' + CONVERT (VARCHAR, c_columnA % 60), 2)
```

but that's not the result.  Any idea's how the data might be being casted?

Here a sample of the data:

```
INT |TIME
4680001|13:00
4680001|13:00
4596001|12:45
3846001|10:41
4320001|12:00
```

Comment: What does that number `2910519` represent? *Why* should it be `10:41`?

Comment: ***Why*** should those figures give those results?  `2910519 / 600000` = `4.850865`, so I'm not sure where `10:41` is meant to come from.

Comment: @HansKesting it should be 10:41 because a front end displays it as that, we do not know how the front end is converting it

Comment: @Mike And you want us to reverse engineer how it is casted with only one example?

Comment: @Mike: Then you should say that in your question. How are *we* supposed to know that that it's something that your front end does (and that you do not know what method is used)?

Comment: @AndriyM Well I'm asking the question how much the data be casted, and I give an example of a source and result....

Comment: @Mike - You are right, didn't see the second one. Do you have records that have the same time (or that are close enough)?, do they have the same value for `columnA`?

Comment: Do you have a copy of the source code for the front end?

Comment: The difference between the times seems disproportionate to the difference between the encoded values. Could the encoded values possibly include dates?

Comment: If you ignore the trailing 1, the value could be hundredths of a second since midnight - e.g. `select dateadd(ms,384600 * 100,'19000101')` gives `19000101 10:41`

Comment: The figures in your last edit seem more consistent and, I dare say, easier to decipher. I would post an answer but someone has already cast the last close vote. Do you think you still need our help?

Comment: @AndriyM Yes i honestly have no idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's already in the comments but I'll post this as an answer:

If you ignore the trailing 1, the value could be hundredths of a second since midnight -

e.g. `select dateadd(ms,384600 * 100,'19000101')` gives `19000101 10:41`

or as a query:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
(i INT, t VARCHAR(5))
INSERT @t (i,t)
VALUES (4680001,'13:00'),
(4680001,'13:00'),
(4596001,'12:45'),
(3846001,'10:41'),
(4320001,'12:00')

SELECT DATEADD(s,i/100,'19000101'), t
FROM @t
```

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables sometimes there is a trailing 4